# Trouble Deploying ASP.NET Core React App on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET and AWS, and I'm encountering some issues while trying to deploy an ASP.NET Core React application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Here's what I've done so far:

I created a project using the JetBrains Rider template for ASP.NET Core React.
Without making any changes to the code, I successfully published it to a local folder.
Next, I zipped the files from the local folder and uploaded them to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
However, when I check the Elastic Beanstalk environment, I see that the health status is "Degraded," and there are errors reported. Specifically, the error message mentions:
`ERROR Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'. Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error.. During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.`

I'm unsure about what could be causing these errors, and I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Can someone please help me understand what might be going wrong and provide steps to rectify it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!